# matDatepicker ignores locale setting (Angular 16 standalone)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular16

i have set my locales settings in the main.ts like this:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
        { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-GB' },
        { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB' },
        { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS },
        { provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } },
        {
            provide: DateAdapter,
            useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
            deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS],
        },
    ],
}
```

still, the datepicker shows up in german instead of english.

[image]

i have made sure to have istalled `@angular/material-moment-adapter` and `@angular/material` both in the same version of `16.1.4`.

when i go to my component i can @inject `LOCALE_ID` and `MAT_DATE_LOCALE` and both return `en-GB` when i log them.

I also tried to actively set the the local directly in the component by following materials official approach:

```
constructor(private adapter: DateAdapter<any>) {
    this.adapter.setLocale('en-GB');
}
```

And still, the overlay pops up in German.
I am not even located in Germany nor have i set my OS nor browser to german.

i have searched my entire project for references to `DE`, `de-DE` and `de_de` but there is nothing.

The result is the same in all browsers (chrome, firefox, edge and brave)

I appreciate any idea that might help advancing towards the a solution.

Comment: The datepicker in the screenshot is in english. What makes you think it is in german?

Comment: If you need american variant (MM/DD/YYYY), then you should use ```en-US``` instead of ```en-GB```. But as I can see from your popup, I agree with JSON Derulo,- looks english to me.

Comment: @json-derulo ok i got totally trolled by my own brain. you two are of course right. It slipped me because in the official docs the english version of the popup uses just one letter per day. and the app was indeed german in the past where they used two letters per day. so i just did not realize that it is now english with two letters. sorry for wasting your time and many thanks. i would have blindly continued to search for the non-existing error without your comments. have a good time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the popup is in english as pointed out in the comment.

It slipped me because in the official docs the english version of the popup uses just one letter per day. and the app was indeed german in the past where they used two letters per day. so i just did not realize that it is now english with two letters.